# Bounding text inside a shape

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

On canvas I have a background shape and text,

how do you emulate something like `overflow:hidden;` from css to the text?

Basically the text overflows the shape and I'm trying to mask/clip it, but couldn't find any solutions. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jonke thanks, but I think the question pertains to KineticJS as well since I'm using KineticJS for the text and shape. What do you think?

Comment: vvMINOvv ,ah, maybe you could make your question a bit more longer and with an actual sample of your current kineticjs code.

Comment: do you mean like this, http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-wrap-text-tutorial/? or do you want to truncate your text? then you must do it yourself but you can use http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-text-metrics/ so you maximize your text.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new background canvas, set its width and height to that of the desired bounding box, draw the text on it, and then draw the background canvas to the primary one.

To create a background canvas, just do

```
var tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
```

but don't attach it to any other DOM node. You can then set the `.width` and `.height` of the canvas, get its context and draw on it.

To draw it back to the visible canvas, just pass the background canvas to drawImage of the main canvas context:

```
mainCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(tempCanvas, x, y);
```

Comment: That's definitely the closest thing to the answer I'm looking for but it doesn't solve my problem.

I currently have this as the text, and I need it to fit in the outline behind it  https://dl.dropbox.com/u/21188944/masking.png